# Time complexity(theta) for loops with special case

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, computer-science, induction

I can't able to find the theta for some type of code  like.

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
 for(j=i;j>=1;j=j/3){
 ....
 }
}
```

How to find the theta for the above code.

It will be really helpful if some one help me how to find it in general case like.

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
 for(j=i;j>=1;j=j/K){
 ....
 }
}
```

Ps: I know it for k=2 which is n*logn

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is `i=j` what you want to do? Why?

Comment: what is `j`'s initial value?

Comment: sorry, please find my modified code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the inner loop out. 

Each iteration of the inner loop takes `Theta(log_K(i))` iterations, since the iterator `j` starts from `i` and decays exponentially.

So, you have to combine that with the outer loop now, which is a simple incremental loop.

Thus, the outer loop takes:

```
Theta(log_K(1) + log_K(2) + log_K(3) + ... + log_K(n)) = 
= Theta(log_K(1*2*...*n)) = Theta(log_K(n!)) = 
= Theta(n*log_K(n)) = Theta(nlogn)
```

[The last equality is because `log_K(x) = log_2(x) / log_2(K)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithmic_identities), but `log_2(K)` is a constant.

---

I am assuming you mean `for(j=i;j>=1;j=j/3){`, and NOT `for(i=j;j>=1;j=j/3){` (i and j switched on initialization)

Comment: Thank you so much this is really helpful. 

But, I am confused with log_K(i), can you please provide me the explanation for getting log_K(i) for the inner loop.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Amit

Can you please give me the explanation for Theta(log_K(i)) (inner loop)

Comment: @user2553748 By dividing by `k` each iteration, you make the variable `j` decay exponentially in `k`. (it is first `j`, then `j/k`, then `j/k^2`, then `j/k^3`, ...). exponential decay mean it is O(log(i))